# Excel VBA - Delete Rows Based on Criteria

Tags: vba, excel

I have a report that I pull everyday that is placed in a very awekward format. It's contains a variable row count by 4 columns organized into unofficial tables based on the Name of each employee.

What I have is an employee name in column B preceded 2 blank rows above and followed by 1 blank row of data below.

What I want to accomplish is loop through the data, identify cells in column B <> blank, delete the entire 2 rows below that cell, and delete the entire 1 row above that cell.

Below is what I have so far. not much:

```
Sub test()

Dim currentSht As Worksheet
Dim startCell As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lastCol As Long
Dim i as integer

Set currentSht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

Set startCell = currentSht.Range("A1")
lastRow = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lastCol = startCell.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For i = lastRow To 1
    If Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without making major changes to your code, try this:

```
For i = lastRow To 1 Step - 1
    If Cells(i, "B").Value <> "" Then
    Range(Cells(i, "B").Offset(1), Cells(i, "B").Offset(2)).EntireRow.Delete  'delete two below
    Cells(i, "B").Offset(-1).EntireRow.Delete ' delete one above
```

You already get to your non-blank cell (ie `Cells(i,"b")`).  To reference a range in relation to a cell you already have, use `OFFSET`.

So, and in this order, you select a range of cells from one below your cell `Offset(1)` to two cells below `Offset(2)'.  Change this range to`ENTIREROW` for those cells, and delete.

Then you select the cell above `Offset(-1)`, select the `ENTIREROW` and delete.

Comment: I am a little confused by this line of code: `Range(Cells(4, 1).Offset(1), Cells(4, 1).Offset(2)).EntireRow.Delete`. Shouldn't my selected range (to be offset) be in reference to cells(i,"B")? I don't know why you are using (4, 1).

Comment: @AndyG was using (4,1) in a quick sample i set up locally, changed to (i, "B"), thanks!

Comment: You are missing the `Step - 1` in the for loop.

Comment: @ScottCraner can you elaborate?  I removed End Sub, as there is an End If and Next that I omitted just to show the row.delete portion, would it be better to add those for completeness?

Comment: If you are looping from a larger number to a smaller you need to tell it to step -1.  The default is step +1. It will do the loop once then end.

Comment: @scottcraner never iterated down before thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

as per your question narrative you'd possibly need to delete all rows that has a blank cell in column "B"

should that be the issue than you could (disclaimer: test it on a copy sheet!) simply go like follows:

```
Sub test()    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Offset(, 1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
End Sub
```