# Delete entire rows that meet a criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am stuck with writing code to delete entire rows if they meet certain criteria.
In my case, I want all rows that have at least on column with #N/A Invalid Security to be deleted.
What is the best way to write the code? should I include a filter and then delete?
thanks

Comment: You can loop through each column in each row and record row numers in an array. And delete rows using a for loop

Comment: There are plenty of examples here on how to do this... just remember to step backwards.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel VBA - Delete Rows Based on Criteria](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37668125/excel-vba-delete-rows-based-on-criteria)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the next code, please. If I remember well, "#N/A Invalid Security" is not an error, it is an answer form a source you interogate. So, using it like string should work in this way:

```
Sub DeleteRowByCriteria()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, arr As Variant, rngDel As Range, i As Long, j As Long
    Set sh = ActiveSheet ' use here your sheet
    arr = sh.UsedRange.value
     For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1)
        For j = 1 To UBound(arr, 2)
            If arr(i, j) = "#N/A Invalid Security" Then
                If rngDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rngDel = sh.Cells(i, j): Exit For
                Else
                    Set rngDel = Union(rngDel, sh.Cells(i, j)): Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next
     Next i
     If Not rngDel Is Nothing Then rngDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: WORKED, AMAZING! thank you!!!

Comment: @Vir:  Glad I could help you! But, in such cases, when an answer solved your problem, it is good to tick the code left side check box, in order to make it accepted answer. In this way, somebody searching for a similar problem will know that the answer worked...

Comment: got it! new to this!

Comment: @Vir: You got it, but you did not tick the text box to make it accepted answer...